# Delete the app folder in system accidently

Tags: boot-loop

I delete app folder in system folder which have preloaded .apk , now after i delete , every thing in my phone gone stopped working i turn off my phone and try to turn it on but stuck in boot load and wont come up
whats happened to my phone?
can i solve this problem and how?

i have xperia m dual

Comment: You've deleted the System related files. A lot of them. That's why its stuck. You need to download ROM for your device and flash it on your device. That's only option left now for you. Never mess up with System Folder. In fact, never ever delete anything other than what is in Internal/External Storage.

Comment: ok thank u
solve it with repair through sony pc campaign